# Creating new Service Fabric Cluster on AWS EC2s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to create a 3-node cluster on AWS EC2 instances but get the error

```
"Config validation: Certificate 8BCA4F8D39BDD9998FFFB935D30333984F0C698B 
is not installed on node 10.0.1.56 under My. 
Check the node availability, certificate installation, 
and the remote certificate store read permission on the nodes."
```

I am running the New-ServiceFabricCluster command from another EC2 in the same security group.

I have tried putting spaces in the thumbprint: 8B CA 4F 8D 39 BD D9 99 8F FF B9 35 D3 03 33 98 4F 0C 69 8B

I can verify that the certificate is installed under "LocalMachine\My" via Powershell WinRM (also when I remote onto the EC2 instance):

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -match "8BCA4F8D39BDD9998FFFB935D30333984F0C698B"}}
```

Firewalls have been turned off on all machines.

Inbound rules have been added to the security group for 19000,19080 etc.

Does the New-ServiceFabricCluster cmdlet use a specific port that needs opening? I have not had this issue installing on Azure or on an On-Premise network.

The results of running TestConfiguration.ps1 are:

```
LocalAdminPrivilege        : True
IsJsonValid                : False
IsCabValid                 : 
RequiredPortsOpen          : 
RemoteRegistryAvailable    : 
FirewallAvailable          : 
RpcCheckPassed             : 
NoConflictingInstallations : 
FabricInstallable          : 
Passed                     : False
```

Comment: Have you copied the certificate thumbprint from your certificate details or you typed it in the command? is very common when you copy it to get some dodgy chars that is not rendered in the command.

Comment: I've re-typed the beginning of the thumbprint to get rid of the dodgy char at the beginning, so that's not the issue unfortunately

Comment: @SturmUndDrang Even though it says that "certificate is not installed", it might not be the real issue. Check `DeploymentTraces` for more specific info what went wrong. This folder should be created in the location from where you run `TestConfiguration` script.